# Importing into SUPER column fails when COPYing from avro file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to COPY from avro file into SUPER column? I'm using following query to import.

```
copy small_table
    from 's3://xxxx/redshift_chunk_1782431332154490799.avro'
    access_key_id 'xxx'
    secret_access_key 'xxx'
    format as avro 'auto ignorecase'
```

But it fails with following error in `stl_load_errors`:

```
colname: v_json
type: super
raw_field_value: "{ "key": 1234, "key2": null, "key3": "meh" }"
err_reason: Format with multiple values without array or object
```

It works if I'm importing from CSV file. I'd like this column and value to be loaded as `object` in SUPER.

Test avro file is [here](https://transfer.sh/1M8RVq9/redshift_chunk_1782431332154490799.avro).

Comment: @john Rotenstein I am facing the same issue loading it from Avro file. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @expert is the question-asker.