# Redshift uses wrong timezone when loading from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Redshift allows loading time-related types using its epoch representation as stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-timeformat) by setting `timeformat 'epochmillisecs'` parameter of COPY command. It works great for TIMESTAMPs but something is broken for TIME columns.

Epoch value 1636984022000 (ms) that corresponds to 13:47:02.572000 is being imported as 22:41:11 by Redshift. I can see that it matches 13:47:02 UTC at PST (-08:00).

I tried `alter user awsuser set timezone to 'UTC'` and `set timezone to default` but it doesn't seem to help. What am I missing ?

Comment: **Side-note:** Sometimes timezone issues can be hard to diagnose because SQL clients perform a conversion on the field when displaying data. A trick I use is to convert the timestamp to `TEXT` so that the SQL client does not alter its contents. So, try selecting the data as `SELECT field::TEXT` to verify how it is _actually_ being stored. Might be relevant in your situation, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I'm shocked but you're right. Thank you so much!! Please leave your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Could you please advise on https://stackoverflow.com/q/68367270/226895 as well ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes timezone issues can be hard to diagnose because SQL clients perform a conversion on the field when displaying data.

A trick I use is to convert the timestamp to `TEXT` so that the SQL client does not alter its contents. So, try selecting the data as `SELECT field::TEXT` to verify how it is *actually* being stored.

This prevents the SQL client from performing any nicely-intentioned timezone conversion and lets you see the 'real' underlying data.